# If i add 2 double data type value, the result is round off and print.How do i get the exact output in double?

Tags: c#, output, user-defined-data-types

I need to add double values and display it result. But the resulting value was wrong.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        string s = "HackerRank ";
        int i1 = 12;
        double d1 = 4.0;
        string s1 = "is the best place to learn and practice coding!";
        int sum = 0; string s2 = string.Empty;
        sum = sum+i + i1;
        s2 = s2 + s + s1;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}",d,d1,(d+d1).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(s2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[the output snapshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2IU2.png)

My expected output is 4.0+4.0=8.0

But the output value is roundoff. Can anyone provide the reason and solution for this question?

Comment: For decimal precision use Decimals!

Comment: yes Taw it an good answer,But my requirement is only use double .not decimals.anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show the output in x.xx format you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F2}+{1:F2}={2:F2}",d,d1,d+d1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine( String.Format("{0:0.0}", d + d2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `ToString()` on each double

```
Console.WriteLine($"{d.ToString("G1")}+{d1.ToString("G1")}=(d + d1).ToString("G1")});
```

Comment: Thank you. Great Answers.i will try these

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F}+{1:F}={2:F}",d,d1,d+d1);
```

"F" is Fixed-Point Format Specifier. You can also specify the desired number of decimal places by changing the "F" to "F2,F3 and so on" as per your requirement or leave it as "F" so that it can return output according to the variable.